# Swipe / slide to unlock button in .net Maui

Tags: c#, xaml, controls, maui, slide

Is there any NuGet package or a way to create an animated swipe button in .net Maui?

If possible it should look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: You can try to use the canvas or the skiasharp to draw a such control by yourself.